# WSO2IS 5.3.0 XSS Protection

Tags: wso2, xss, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 in carbon.xml there is still the XSS prevention config which was introduced with 5.0.0 SP1. It is described in the   [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Mitigating+Cross+Site+Scripting+%28XSS%29+Attacks) as well.

```
<XSSPreventionConfig>
   <Enabled>true</Enabled>
   <Rule>allow</Rule>
   <Patterns>
      <!--Pattern></Pattern-->
   </Patterns>
</XSSPreventionConfig>
```

The configuration is read by the tomcat XSSValve. But in the default installation WSO2IS package the tomcat valve configuration is missing. Basically leaving the XSSPreventionConfig useless.

Is the configuration still needed? Can I remove the configuration from carbon.xml or do I need to configure XSSValve in tomcat?